# Is there a good video or documentation that helps me learn about Null safety in Dart?

Tags: dart

I started learning Dart this week and I got into some exercises. When I was writing some code I had a lot of errors about null safety and the operators `?` and `!`. Is there a good video or documentation that help me learn it?

For example the exercise was to "Create a program that asks the user to enter their name and their age. Print out a message that tells how many years they have to be 100 years old."

My code:

```dart
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var name = stdin.readLineSync();

  var str_age = stdin.readLineSync();

  int age = int.parse(str_age);

  var ageToHundred = 100 - age;

  print("Hello $name you have $ageToHundred to get to 100");
}
```

With the help of ChatGPT I found out that if I add the `!` operator like this `var str_age = stdin.readLineSync()!;`. It works now but why?

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65749204/dart-identifier-with-exclamation-mark-in-the-back

Comment: Have your read: https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety ?

Comment: And for this specific problem: ["The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" when using stdin.readLineSync()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66695339/)